# How does JavaScript treat the ++ operator?

Tags: javascript, operators, type-conversion, coercion

JavaScript does funky automatic conversions with objects:

```
var o = {toString: function() {return "40"; }};
print(o + o);
print((o+1)+o);
print((o*2) + (+o));
```

will print:

```
4040
40140
120
```

This is because +, if any of the arguments are objects/strings, will try to convert all the arguments to strings then concatenate them. If all arguments are numbers, it adds them together. * and unary + convert objects to numbers using toString (as well as valueOf, not shown here).

What does JavaScript do for the ++ operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)

> ### 11.3 Postfix Expressions
>
> **Syntax**
>
> PostfixExpression :
>
> - LeftHandSideExpression
> - LeftHandSideExpression [no LineTerminator here] ++
> - LeftHandSideExpression [no LineTerminator here] --
>
> **11.3.1 Postfix Increment Operator**
>
> The production *PostfixExpression :
>   LeftHandSideExpression [no
>   LineTerminator here] ++* is evaluated
>   as follows:
>
> 1. Evaluate LeftHandSideExpression.
> 2. Call GetValue(Result(1)).
> 3. Call ToNumber(Result(2)).
> 4. Add the value 1 to Result(3), using the same rules as for the + operator
>      (section 11.6.3).
> 5. Call PutValue(Result(1), Result(4)).
> 6. Return Result(3).

---

This is pseudo javascript code of how postInc works:

```
function postInc(a) {
  var x = +a; // Converts a to a number, Section 11.4.6 Unary + Operator
  a = x + 1;
  return x;
}
```

Edit: As [mikesamuel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20394/) said: it's not parseInt. Updated to reflect that.

Comment: There's no parseInt involved.
It converts to a number, so the result might have a fractional part.

consider

  x = '4.5', ++x

and the internal number conversion scheme will recognize hex in strings

  x = '0xA', ++x

Comment: @Mikesamuel: Yep, my bad. It was supposed to be in pseudo code... I have updated it now. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

The following code illustrates this well:

```
var a = {toString: function() {return "40"; }};
nl(typeof a);
nl(typeof +a);
nl(typeof a);
nl(typeof (a++));
nl(a);
nl(typeof a);
```

The output is:

```
object
number
object
number
41
number
```

Unary plus converts the object to a number and doesn't modify it. a++ first converts the object to a number, **then returns that number**, and then increments the number, storing the value in a.

This is opposed to another possible solution, where a++ would first return the object, and then do the conversion to a number and incrementation.

Answer (score 1):

The `++` operator does a "toNumber" conversion (basically a combination of type rules and the valueOf function).  Basically for any resolve expression

```
 resolveExpression++
```

The steps taken by the JS engine are

```
 <temp> = toNumber(resolveExpression);
 resolveExpression = <temp> + 1;
 <result> = <temp>
```

For non-atomic resolve expressions, eg. `base.resolve++` or `base["resolve"]++`, etc. `base` is resolved only once and then reused.  In any sane case this is irrelevant, however it's important if the value being incremented is an object with a valueOf implementation that changes the base object.

eg.

```
base = {};
base.value = {valueOf:function(){base = {}; return 5;}}
base.value++;
```